# Will a (non-constant) exponential polynomial have at least one root?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to figure out if an exponential polynomial of the form
$$\sum_{j=1}^na_j e^{b_jz}$$
(with z a complex number) will necessarily have one zero.

I think that it won't, because each term individually cannot be zero (eliminating the possibility that all terms are zero) and so all the terms would have to add to be zero. But that isn't guaranteed at all. Does that sound about right?

Comment: If we look at the case of $f(z)=a_1e^{b_1z}+a_2e^{b_2z}$, then $f(z)=0$ means that $a_1e^{b_1z}=-a_2e^{b_2z}$. Rearranging, we have
$$
-\frac{a_1}{a_2}=e^{(b_2-b_1)z}.
$$
In the case where $b_1\neq b_2$, this should definitely yield a solution.

Comment: If the $b_i$ are rational, I also think you can reduce it to the polynomial case.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews [Exponential polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_polynomial#Definition)

Comment: Ah, I read the body, not the title. @Pp I've edited the body to say "exponential polynomial."

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are dealing with integer $b_i$, as per the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_polynomial), this can be written as $e^{-bz}P(e^z)$ for  some (regular) polynomial $P$ and some non-negative integer $b$.

This has a root exactly when $P(x)$ has a non-zero root, since $z\mapsto e^z$ is onto $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$. That happens exactly when $P$ has more than one term.

Comment: I don't understand how that factorization follows, and it looks as if your last statement to me already assumes the property I'm looking to prove. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Think it through. I'm not assuming anything about exponential polynomials - $P$ is a regular polynomial. As for the factorization, there are only a finite number of terms.